# How to add controller to streamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, zip

**Flutter**
***Dart***

I am a beginner in flutter and i am trying to add controller to streamBuilderWidget  so i can dispose it but i have no idea  where should i put the controller.. i tried this

the stream below as a widget not function

```
StreamController<QuerySnapshot> controller;
        void dispose() {
            super.dispose();
            controller.close();
          }
        
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            controller = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();
          }
        
         StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.documentUid).snapshots(),
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
         if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
              child: circulearProgress(),
            );
}
```

in this code it never disposed or closed the stream:(

Anyone who edits my code in the right way will be very grateful to him , thanks friends

Answer (score 5):

StreamController is like a pipeline. In your case, that pipeline went from water supplier to your house, there is no need to worried about what goes in there.
But if you want to set up a pipeline from your washing machine to the draining hole, that is where you need to use StreamController.
Example:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final NumberController controller = NumberController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              InputWidget(controller: controller,),
              OutputWidget(controller: controller,)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberController {
  //This is the pipeline of "number"
  final StreamController<int> controller = StreamController<int>.broadcast();

  //This is where your "number" go in
  Sink<int> get inputNumber => controller.sink;

  //This is where your "number" go out
  Stream<int> get outputNumber => controller.stream;

  //Dispose
  void dispose() {
    controller.close();
  }
}

class InputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final NumberController controller;

  const InputWidget({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
            controller.inputNumber.add(Random().nextInt(10));
        },
    child: Text(
      'Random Number'
    ),);
  }
}

class OutputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final NumberController controller;

  const OutputWidget({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: controller.outputNumber,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.toString() : 'No data');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for awesome example , i have this handleDelete(){
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").doc(currentUser.uid + widget.documentUid).collection("handleCountM2").limit(1).snapshots().listen((value) {
    value.docs.forEach((element) {
      element.reference.delete();
    });
  });

  }

how could i close it when i press on the back button

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use StreamController. StreamBuilder you are using closes the stream internally.

Comment: thanks for this information but i am trying to close this function when i press on the back  bottom  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").doc(currentUser.uid + widget.documentUid).collection("handleCountM2").limit(1).snapshots().listen((value) {
    value.docs.forEach((element) {
      element.reference.delete();
    });
  });

  }

how could i close it when i press on the back button

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you seem to want to close the listener in the method below:

```dart
void handleDelete() {
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").doc(currentUser.uid + widget.documentUid).collection("handleCountM2").limit(1).snapshots()
  .listen((value) { 
     value.docs.forEach((element) { 
       element.reference.delete(); 
     }); 
  }); 
}
```

You can do that by getting a reference to the stream subscription and calling `.cancel` on the subscription.

Calling `.listen` on a stream returns a stream subscription object like this:

```
StreamSubscription handleDeleteStreamSubscription =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").doc(currentUser.uid + widget.documentUid).collection("handleCountM2").limit(1).snapshots()
  .listen((value) { 
     value.docs.forEach((element) { 
       element.reference.delete(); 
     }); 
  });
```

Cancelling the subscription is done like this:

```
handleDeleteStreamSubscription.cancel();
```